# Why the dict of Python is not affected as a parameter passed into the function?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I know the the way of dict passed into function in Python is like as the passing by reference in C++. So, I think that the function can change the value of dict which is passed into. But, the results of the three experiments are inconsistent. Here is my question: why the `fun2` can not change the value of `x`, while the `fun1` and `func2` can do it?

My Python version is 3.10.12

```py
def fun1(x):
    x["c"] = "c"

def fun2(x):
    x = {"ds": "ds"}

def fun3(x):
    c = {"ds": "ds"}
    x["c"] = c

def main():
    d1 = {"a": "a", "b": "b", "c": {}}
    d2 = {"a": "a", "b": "b", "c": {}}
    d3 = {"a": "a", "b": "b", "c": {}}

    fun1(d1)
    fun2(d2["c"])
    fun3(d3)

    print(d1)
    print(d2)
    print(d3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output

```
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'c': 'c'}
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'c': {}}
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'c': {'ds': 'ds'}}
```

I try to figure out this problem, but nothing happened.

---------Update------------

Thank you @Albin Paul, I know the key of this question.
**Python pass the parameters by value, just like `fun` and `fun1`.**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void fun(int *x){
    // simple use of pointer
    // the operation on `*x` will affect `*a`. Because `x` and `a` are pointers.
    *x = 10;
}

void fun1(int *x){
    // pointer passed by value
    // `x` of func1 is the formal parameter, `a` of main is the actual Parameter
    // therefore, the operation on `x` will not affect `a`
    // But the operation on `*x` will affect `*a`. like `fun1`
    x = new int(20);
    std::cout << "This is function1. " << *x << std::endl;
}

void fun2(int *&x){
    // pointer passed by reference
    // `x` of func2 is the reference of `a`
    // the operation on `x` will affect `a`
    // the operation on `*x` will affect `*a` too.
    x = new int(30);
    std::cout << "This is function2. " << *x << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    int *a = new int(1);
    fun(a);
    std::cout << *a << std::endl;
    fun1(a);
    std::cout << *a << std::endl;
    fun2(a);
    std::cout << *a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result is as follows.

```
10
This is function1. 20
10
This is function2. 30
30
```

Comment: `my_dict = ...` creates a new variable `my_dict` that hides the old variable `my_dict` ... `my_dict[key] = ...` modifies the existing `my_dict`  that will be preserved

Comment: "I know the the way of dict passed into function in Python is like as the passing by reference in C++." **absolutely incorrect**. Python *never* uses call by reference (or call by value, for that matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar example

```
def fun1(x):
    x[0] = 1
    x[1] = 2
def fun2(x):
    x = [1, 2]


def main():
    d1 = [3, 3]
    d2 = [3, 3]

    fun1(d1)
    fun2(d2)
    
    print(d1)
    print(d2)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In `fun2`, you are passing the variable by reference, but the reference is being passed by value.
It is similar to C++ concept of pointer passing by value and pointer passing by reference.

```
int fun1(void *x){

}

int fun2(void *&x){

}
```

So if you pass a pointer to `fun2` the pointer reflects the changes after the function is called but not in `fun1`.

So Python passes references by value.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know the key of this question.